# Qt generic widget handling

Tags: c++, qt

I am using qt (pretty new to it). I am currently using filing to save user checkbox states. Whenever the user opens that windows file is read and implemented, but there are a lot of checkboxes and I am using a lot of if statements (to load previous states). I am just curious if there is a generic way to do this as I have a lot of windows and checkboxes to handle.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each QObject instance has a name, available via QObject::objectName, and you can use a combination of the QObject::findChild methods to find all of the QCheckBox instances under whatever parent widget contains all of these. Then you can extract the name and checkbox state to write to the file. When you read the file in, you reverse that process.

The caveat is that the names of your objects need to remain consistent; through the life cycle of your program, if you change a name of a QCheckBox, files containing that name either become invalid, or you have to handle the name conversion. What I would recommend is to use Qt Designer to manually set the names of the QCheckBox instances so that they make sense based on what they represent rather than the automatically-generated names they get otherwise.